# avoid nested subscribe if there is a forkjoin inside

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Here is my code in angular

```
this.service.save(body).subscribe(
    resp => {
       this.dialog.confirmation({
          message: 'save object successfully!'
       })
       .subscribe((ok) => {
            if(ok) {
               this.pro.status = resp.status;
            this.loadingData(resp);
            const s1 = this.service.getSummary(this.id);
            const s2 = this.service.getCost(this.id);
            forkJoin([s1, s2]).subscribe([r1, r2]) => {
               this.view = r1;
               this.list = r2;
            }
          }
        });
     }
);
```

So there are many levels of subscribe. Not only it is ugly also the result is wrong and I can't not find it out by debugging. How can I rewrite it with rxjs operators?

Comment: What is happening in loadingData()?

Comment: I can load data from `resp`. But it seems there is a memory leak

Comment: There are some good answers already, with different RxJS operator, so I will not add more. But to avoid memory leaks (and other negative side effects) try to never subscribe inside a subscribe and always unsubscribe from your Observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify it using the `RxJS` operators, like the following:

```js
// import { EMPTY, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
// import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.service
  .save(body)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((result) =>
      // Merge the main observable with the dialog confirmation one..
      // and map it to an object that contains the result from both observables.
      this.dialog
        .confirmation({ message: 'save object successfully!' })
        .pipe(map((confirmed) => ({ result, confirmed })))
    ),
    mergeMap(({ result, confirmed }) => {
      if (confirmed) {
        this.pro.status = result.status;
        this.loadingData(result);
        const s1 = this.service.getSummary(this.id);
        const s2 = this.service.getCost(this.id);
        return forkJoin([s1, s2]);
      }
      // Don't emit any value, if the dialog is not confirmed:
      return EMPTY;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(([r1, r2]) => {
    this.view = r1;
    this.list = r2;
  });
```

**Note:** To handle the memory leaks, it's highly recommended to `unsubscribe` from the observable when you don't need it anymore, and this can be achieved based on your use cases, such as assigning the `subscribe` function result to a `Subscription` variable and calling `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook, or using a `Subject` with `takeUntil` operator and calling `next`/`complete` functions in `ngOnDestroy`.

And here is how to use the `unsubscribe` method for example:

```js
// import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    subscription: Subscription 
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscription = this.service.save(body)
        // >>> pipe and other RxJS operators <<<
        .subscribe(([r1, r2]) => {
          this.view = r1;
          this.list = r2;
        });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

You can read more about that here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Comment: I appreciate your input. So how can I unsubscribe in my code ?

Comment: I updated my answer to include one of the ways to do that, and you can read more about it in the provided link.

Answer (score 2):

This should be roughly equivalent:

```
this.service.save(body).pipe(

  mergeMap(resp => 
    this.dialog.confirmation({
      message: 'save object successfully!'
    }).pipe(
      // This filter acts like your `if(ok)` statement. There's no 
      // else block, so if it's not okay, then nothing happens. The 
      // view isn't updated etc.
      filter(ok => !!ok),
      mapTo(resp)
    )
  ),

  tap(resp => {
    this.pro.status = resp.status;
    // If the following line mutates service/global state,
    // it probably won't work as expected
    this.loadingData(resp); 
  }),

  mergeMap(_ => forkJoin([
    this.service.getSummary(this.id),
    this.service.getCost(this.id)
  ]))

).subscribe([view, list]) => {
  this.view = view;
  this.list = list;
});
```

Comment: What is `ok => !!ok`? I saw `!!` first time.

Comment: @Bigeyes `!!` coerces values to a boolean. If ok was already a boolean, it does nothing.